# Any light software to view doc, docx and ppt with easy on Win10?

Tags: microsoft-word, word-processor, documentation-viewer

MS Office, LibreOffice are too heavy and require a few moments to launch.

Is there any program starting and responding very quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to view the files and not edit them... there is a free software offered by Microsoft itself for just viewing these files.

I didn't test myself, but I strongly assume that these viewers are faster than a full office suite with editing possibilities so it should start faster.

<s>Just download the [PowerPoint Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13) and [Word Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=4) from Microsoft.</s>

Unfortunately, Microsoft stopped supporting these programs. You could try [Microsoft PowerPoint Mobile](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/powerpoint-mobile/9wzdncrfjb5q) or [Microsoft Word Mobile](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/word-mobile/9wzdncrfjb9s) instead.

Comment: These links are now dead, unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnY Thanks, I updated the answer to recommend the latest software instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take a look at [Kingsoft Office Suite 2016 Free (WPS  v10.xxx)](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/software/kingsoft-office-freeware) (my friend uses that).

> WPS Office 2016 Free is a powerful office suite which includes a word
>   processor, a spreadsheet program and a presentation maker. These three
>   programs can help you easily deal with office tasks

**Minimum requirements**

- CPU: Pentium II 266 MHz or higher
- Memory: at least 128 MB
- Hardware: at least 200 MB available space

**Required Operating System:**

- Windows 2000 / Windows XP
- Windows Vista (32bit, 64bit)
- Windows 7 (32bit, 64bit)
- Windows 8
- Windows 10

Comparing to other mentioned softwares, it uses much lesser resources e.g RAM, CPU comparing to rivals like Ms Office and worth a try.